# Why I can't add zero padding to variable

Tags: sass

I would like to know why I can't add two zeros to the right side of a variable in SCSS.

Example code:

```
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
  .animated--#{$i}00 {
    -webkit-animation-duration: #{$i}00ms;
    animation-duration: #{$i}00ms;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
  }
}
```

Is printing

```
.animated--10 {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 10ms;
     animation-duration: 10ms;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
     animation-fill-mode: both;
}
 .animated--20 {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 20ms;
     animation-duration: 20ms;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
     animation-fill-mode: both;
}
 .animated--30 {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 30ms;
     animation-duration: 30ms;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
     animation-fill-mode: both;
}
 .animated--40 {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 40ms;
     animation-duration: 40ms;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
     animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

I have solved the issue already by doing the following (suggested by a coworker):

```
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
  .animated--#{$i * 100} {
    -webkit-animation-duration: #{$i * 100}ms;
    animation-duration: #{$i * 100}ms;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
  }
}
```

I would like to know why adding a right padding zeros to the right side of a variable of SCSS render the example above.

Comment: I think it comes from your compiler, the two zeros are printed correctly when I try your code on SassMeister.

Comment: That's weird because here (https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css) it gives the same result I posted